# plt.subplots() Opens multiple windows outside loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot multiple subplots onto a single window. The subplots are in the single frame but also opens multiple other windows to the number of plots (3).

```
frames = view_specific_year_by_month(df, 2016)
#plt.figure(figsize=[20,7])
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(frames), figsize=[20, 7])
for i in range(len(frames)):
    (sns.FacetGrid(frames[i][frames[i]['Item'].isin(frames[i]['Item'].value_counts().index.values)], hue='Item', height=5,     aspect=2).map(sns.kdeplot, 'Time', shade=True,ax=ax[i]).add_legend())
plt.show()
```

In another post, the individual had the plt.show() inside a loop, in this case it's outside.

```
plt.show()


def view_specific_year_by_month(dataframe, year):
    df = dataframe.filter(['Item', 'Time', 'weekday', 'day', 'month', 'year'], axis=1)
    df = df[(df['year'] == year)]
    frames = []
    for i in range(1, 13):
        tmp = (df[(df['month'] == i) & ((df['Item'].str.contains("Sandwich")) | (df['Item'].str.contains("Coffee")) | (df['Item'].str.contains("Bread")))])
        if not tmp.empty:
            frames.append(tmp)
    return frames
```

[image: Image depicting what loop/plt.show() returns]

Comment: Am I to understand you expect one figure with 3x3 subplots? `FacetGrid` is a figure-level function, which means it creates a new figure everytime you create a new `FacetGrid`. If you want everything on the same figure (same `FacetGrid`) you'll have to rewrite your "get_specific_year" function so that it returns all the data in a single dataframe. Since we do not have access to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I cannot help more than that.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. FacetGrid was the culprit for multiple frames being created.